# Avoiding OutOfMemory exception when making large network requests from Android application

Tags: android, out-of-memory

I am developing an application, and on first launch I anticipate downloading a lot of data in JSON format (say 10-20 MB). All this data is being transferred in a single network request (reason being the data is kind of generated dynamically per request). The fllowing code throws OOM exception when receiving the data (`in builder.append()`):

```
  public static String readToString(InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, "UTF-8"));
    char[] buffer = new char[1024];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
      builder.append(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    in.close();
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

What can I do to avoid this error? I am thinking of trying to save the data to a temporary file and then processing it. But I am unsure whether it will work or not.
Another possibilty seems to be to split the network IO in two parts : first part, the app receives data about what it should download, and second part it actually downloads the data.

Any advice?

Comment: You can save data to temporary file. About way #2, it could be the same if the data is large too. So the good approach is temp files.

Comment: save the data in local file and process it, i think it's a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Follow your first thought - save the data to a temporary file (sdcard please. 20mb in internal storage is too big). You first need to open the connection for your download.

```
InputStream is = URL("your_request_string").openStream();
```

Then create a new File in sdcard

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.dat");
```

Using your newly created file, open a OutputStream.

```
FileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

You can now use this piece of code to do your transfer:

```
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os) {
    final int buffer_size=8192;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
        for(;;)
        {
          int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
          if(count==-1)
              break;
          os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Comment: this is all very nice, but doesn't address the actual problem, which is parsing a 20Mb JSON file.

Comment: i supposed you were already using some sort of json parser that handles large amounts of data. if not, try out Jackson - http://jackson.codehaus.org/

Comment: Yes there is no problem in downloading data and stored it as file in SDCard. but when i read the file and store as arraylist of custom class from SDCard ,it throws outofmemory exception. is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

As of API 11, there is http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/JsonReader.html that is used to read a stream of Json data without allocating the whole big string.

For previous versions, there are a ton of third party JSON libraries that offer event based stream reading capability.